# find closest point of a line to another point

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Given a line $r$ from $a$ to $b$ and a point $c$, how can I find the point $d$ in $r$ whose distance to $c$ is minumum?

I know how to find the minimum distance between $r$ and $c$, but I'm struggling extending that equation to find $d$.

I think there must be a faster way to find $d$ than generating a sphere centered in $c$ with radius equals to the minimum distance between $r$ and $c$ and then checking the intersection point between this sphere and $r$. I'm also doing this in a programming language.

Comment: Is it a line or a line segment between point $a$ and $b$? Makes a difference.

Comment: This kind of problem has been addressed here many times before, such as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717746/closest-point-on-a-line-to-another-point) in two dimensions and even earlier [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13176/how-to-find-a-point-on-a-line-closest-to-another-given-point)  in three dimensions.  This current Question fails to provide enough details to determine in what dimension the problem is posed.

Comment: It's a segment but I think it doesn't matter. It's guaranteed that the minimum distance is inside the segment.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the point $d$, you can compute the gradient of the line r and find the coordinates on the line where the line carried by the gradient intersects c

Answer (score 1):

First project the vector $\vec{ac}$ onto the vector $\vec{ab}$, and then the minimizing point is located at $\vec{a} + \vec{ac}_\parallel$. Here $\vec{ac}_\parallel$ is the component of $\vec{ac}$ in the direction of $\vec{ab}$.